# SWT Why is parent Composite resized after I create a new Composite in parent?

Tags: resize, swt, composite

I want to recreate the functionality and look of `ExpandItem`. I am creating a `Composite` which has a `StyledText` widget and a `Button`. When the `Button` is pressed, a new `Composite` is created below these two, and when it is pressed again, this new `Composite` is hidden. However, after creating the new `Composite`, my parent `Composite` resizes for no reason. I am attaching my code and pictures of my work. I would appreciate any kind of help.

```
Shell shell = new Shell();
//    shell.setSize(400, 400);
Display display = shell.getDisplay();
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

//create outerComp
GridLayout gridLayoutOuterComp = new GridLayout();

GridData gridDataOuterComp = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
gridDataOuterComp.heightHint = 150;

Composite outerComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
outerComp.setLayout(gridLayoutOuterComp);
outerComp.setLayoutData(gridDataOuterComp);

//create innerComp
GridLayout gridLayoutInnerComposite = new GridLayout();
gridLayoutInnerComposite.numColumns = 5;

GridData gridDataInnerComposite = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
gridDataInnerComposite.heightHint = 40;

Composite composite = new Composite(outerComp, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(gridLayoutInnerComposite);
composite.setLayoutData(gridDataInnerComposite);
composite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));

// create the styled text widget
GridData gridDataStyledText = new GridData();
gridDataStyledText.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
gridDataStyledText.horizontalSpan = 4;
gridDataStyledText.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
gridDataStyledText.heightHint = 30;

StyledText widget = new StyledText(composite, SWT.BORDER);
String textNew = "This is StyledText in Composite";
widget.setText(textNew);
widget.setLayoutData(gridDataStyledText);

//create Button
GridData gridDataButton = new GridData();
gridDataStyledText.horizontalSpan = 1;
gridDataButton.heightHint = 30;
gridDataButton.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = false;
gridDataButton.horizontalAlignment = SWT.END;

Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("B1");
button.setLayoutData(gridDataButton);

button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    GridData newCompGridData = new GridData();
    if (counter % 2 == 1) {
      if (newComp != null && !newComp.isVisible()) {
        newComp.setVisible(true);

        GridData newData = new GridData();
        newData.heightHint = 100;
        composite.setLayoutData(newData);

        counter++;
      } else {
        newComp = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        newCompGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        newCompGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        newCompGridData.horizontalSpan = 5;
        newCompGridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        newComp.setLayoutData(newCompGridData);

        GridData newData = new GridData();
        newData.heightHint = 100;
        composite.setLayoutData(newData);

        Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        newComp.setBackground(red);


        counter++;
      }
    } else {
      newComp.setVisible(false);

      GridData newData = new GridData();
      newData.heightHint = 40;
      composite.setLayoutData(newData);

      counter++;
    }
    composite.getParent().layout();
    composite.layout();
    newComp.layout();
  }
```

[image: Before resize]

[image: After resize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```java
GridData newData = new GridData();
newData.heightHint = 100;
composite.setLayoutData(newData);
```

are changing the layout data for `composite` to the default alignment and grab values. They should be:

```java
GridData newData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
newData.heightHint = 100;
composite.setLayoutData(newData);
```

Note: the line

```java
outerComp.setLayoutData(gridDataOuterComp);
```

doesn't do anything because the parent of `outerComp` is using `FillLayout`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this line is irrelevant. Thanks for noticing. I will delete it.